# Deploying node-react app in Heroku - fetch doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, heroku, redux, mlab

I'm trying to deploy a small react app that fetches data mlab - by a node api... locally it's working - when doing fetch - it's returns data - but when deploying to heruko - i get no data back from the Api... i'm newbie to react/node so i must have done something wrong....

Here is the api :

```
    var express    = require('express');
    var cors = require('cors')
    var app        = express();
    var morgan     = require('morgan');

    app.use(morgan('dev'));

    var port     = process.env.PORT || 3007; 
    var mongoose   = require('mongoose');

    mongoose.connect('mongodb://ggg:gggg@ds235418.mlab.com:35418/redux-form');

    var db = mongoose.connection;
    db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));

    db.once('open', function() {
    console.log("DB connection alive");
    });

    var User     = require('./model/user');
    var Message     = require('./model/message');

    var router = express.Router();

        app.get('/messages',function(req, res) {
            Message.find(function(err, messages) {
                if (err)
                    res.send(err);

                res.json(messages);
            });
        });

    app.listen(port);
    console.log('Magic happens on port ' + port);
```

And here is the redux action - from the react app

```
           export function getMessages() {
        const request = fetch(`http://localhost:3007/messages`, { method: 'GET' })
            .then(response => response.json());
        return {
            type: 'GET_MESSAGES',
            payload: request
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, you're making a request to `http://localhost:3007/messages` but when it's deployed to heroku, your server is no longer running on localhost. Have you tried just making the request to `/messages`?

Comment: @tfogo - thanks - do you mean to make the request like this? fetch(`/messages?` - tried - didn't worked.... perhaps there is some other settings to do?

Comment: The command should be `fetch('/messages', { method: 'GET' })`. What errors are you seeing on the command line if any? Can you `console.log` the response to see what it is?